# динамические модальные окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

как сделать при клике на кнопку "выбрать компонент" такую форму? чтобы не создавать для каждого пункта? http://www.ironbook.ru/constructor/

Comment: Создаете одну, при вызове передаете какой-то параметр который подгружает нужный набор.

Comment: а как создать модальное, чтобы при клике оно открывалось и туда передавались данные?

Comment: если сами не можете, поищите плагин по запросу "модальное окно js" или типа того. Ответ на ваш вопрос вне рамок stackoverflow, так как тянет скорее на фриланс.